# Can't assign iterator.next() result to integer array element

Tags: java, json

I have JSONArray with integer numbers and I want to get and put them into my regular integer array. I try to use Iterator, but I catch exception "class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer".

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(settingsFileName));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

int[] dataGrid=new int [11];
int i=0;
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
Iterator<Integer> iterator = msg.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    dataGrid[i]=iterator.next().intValue();
    i++;
}
```

Why it's happening? I created just Integer Iterator, not Long Interator.

UPDATE

This is content of JSONAttay.

[image]

And this is code that forms the file.

```
int[] dataGrid=new int [11];
for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
    dataGrid[i]=1;
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
JSONArray numbers=new JSONArray();
for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
    numbers.add(dataGrid[i]);
obj.put("data",numbers);
obj.put("portName",portName);
FileWriter out=new FileWriter(file);
try{
   out.write(obj.toJSONString());
}
finally {
   out.close();
}
```

I put integer values but somehow they turns to long.

Comment: Looks like your JSONArray contains long values not Integer

Comment: `    dataGrid[i]=((Long)iterator.next()).intValue();` try this

Comment: But there are integer values in array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, look carefully at the debugger output for your `JSONArray`.  Notice that it is displaying the elements as `"{Long@2703} 1"`.  That means:

- the type of the object is `Long`
- the references are the 2703'rd object reference that the debugger has encountered
- the result of calling `toString()` on the object is `"1"`.

So what is happening is that your `next()` calls are returning `Long` objects which you application is trying to cast to `Integer` ... and failing because you cannot cast `Long` to `Integer`.

---

Why is it attempting that cast?  (You didn't write a cast!)

It is because you declared the iterator as follows:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator
```

So when you call `next()` the compiler adds an *implicit* type cast of the result to  the iterator type's generic parameter type: `Integer`.

(Actually, there is something suspicious about this.  If you were using the standard `org.json` API, this should not compile.

```
 Iterator<Integer> iterator = msg.iterator();
```

The version of `json.org.JSONArray that I am looking at declares`iterator()`as`Iterator iterator()`.  But you can't assign`Iterator`to`Iterator` without an (unchecked!) typecast, and there is no typecast in your code.)

---

Why are the elements of the `JSONArray` all `Long`?

I guess that's just how it is implemented.   Note that the *specification* doesn't say what the actual types of the objects returned by the iterator will be.

---

So what is the correct way to code your use-case?

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(settingsFileName));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

int[] dataGrid = new int[11];
int i = 0;
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
Iterator<Object> iterator = msg.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Number num = (Number) (iterator.next());
    dataGrid[i] = number.intValue();
    i++;
}
```

This will work no matter which `Number` subclass is used by JSONArray to represent the array values.

Note that it doesn't matter which integer type was used when you serialized the JSON.  That type information is not encoded in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The value read from JSON is greater that the valid limit of Integer type. That is why Java is converting to Long instead of Integer.

If you are guessing what that integer limit is, it is defined in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and is (2^31)-1

Also take care of `intValue()` because it will truncate or round the value if it is greater than the limit of Integer.

And regarding to your doubt:

> Why it's happening? I created just Integer Iterator, not Long
>   Interator.

It's because the iterator doesn't know the type of the content until you execute `next()` on it (it would be pointless to pre-iterate the contents when defining the iterator and then againg when you use it).

Comment: Please, take a look at updates in the question. There are integer numbers in JSONArray.

Comment: @Eluv - your screenshot shows that they are `Long` objects.  Like Paco is saying.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But can anybody tell me why are they long? I pasted the code that shows, that I put values like integers.